# What is the alternate of headerCt.getMenu(); in Ext JS 3

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am using Ext JS 3 and I need to get ahold of the menu of my column header. I tried to use afterrender of grid.

My code is somewhat like

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: function() {                                        
        var menu = this.headerCt.getMenu();// wrong
    }
}
```

But apparently `headerCt` is not available in Ext JS 3. What other possible options can I use? I did not get any ideas from the Docs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For getting column header menu in lower version of ExtJS try this.

```
afterRender: function () {
    var getMenu = this.view.hmenu.items;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Now I am getting Menu Items in column header. Thanks for all help. It works.